# NSPopUpButton set it to the first item

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nspopupbutton, nscontrol

I have a *clear* button in my Mac OS app.
When the button is pressed, it clears all the values of the form and resets the `NSPopUpButton` to the first item.

The question is how do I change the `NSPopUpButton` control with code.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can call:

Objective C:

```
[myPopupButton selectItemAtIndex:0]
```

Swift:

```
myPopupButton.selectItem(at: 0)
```

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPopUpButton_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

When argument is 0 it means **nil**, and that works. If you put other number (for example 2 ) this will not work because the argument is not number!!!

Comment: 0 doesn't always equal nil